# Fixing the wrong 'bit'

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to fix up data where a column which is storing a number of bit flags in an int column.

What's happened is somewhere along the lines, an incorrect flag has been set (6) so I need to prepare a script to fix up the affected records.

I've tried performing some queries to extract data that appears wrong but it's based on assumption and I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do it.

Some facts:

- The bit that should have been set is `8`, but `6` was used
- The column is currently storing up to 23 bits to represent on/off states for properties (has garden / is furnished / is house / parking etc)
- Some records are affected, some aren't

Considering the bit `6` is invalid is there something clever I can do to pull these records out based on that fact?

Comment: Perhaps it involves something using a remainder? Pull all the valid bits in a column, if there's a remainder, that's the affected record?

Comment: Do you mean that bit #6 was set, or that the field was set to 6?

Comment: That is, do you mean that bit #6 (2^6 = 64) was set, or that the field was masked with 6 instead of 8 (attempting to set bit #3 (2^3=8))?

Comment: @Blorgbeard 6 was masked (?) instead of 8, attempting to set bit #3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about `bit masking` here in this case.

With that assumption, I do not think you will be able to just query the data for a fix.  The way `bit masking` works is to add up the values of all the bits(i.e. convert the binary to an int) so the following mask: `1001` would be stored as 9

If you used 6 instead of 8 it would be the same as if the 4 and 2 bit were both set.  So your query would return all valid records where the 4 and 2 bit are on.

Using the same example if instead of 8 you accidentally used 6 then `1001` becomes 7 instead but how would you differentiate that from `0111` which would correctly be masked as 7?

Comment: Maybe, but the data is stored in a way that if bits 1, 4 & 32 are `on` the value is stored as `37`.

Comment: I see, so if you have a valid bit(from the column value) then you may be able to use your suggestion of subtracting off the valid ones and see if you have a remainder.

Comment: "I do not think you will be able to just query the data for a fix" indeed, the magic wand will have to stay in the drawer for this one.  I'll have suck it up and fix the data manually. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Note that bit 31 can be problematic when handling 32-bit signed values.  Otherwise:

```
-- Check each bit in an integer.
declare @Sample as Int = 6;
with Bits as (
  select Cast( 1 as BigInt ) as BitMask, 0 as BitPosition
  union all
  select Bitmask * 2, BitPosition + 1
    from Bits
    where BitPosition < 31 )
  select BitPosition, BitMask,
    case when Cast( @Sample as BigInt ) & BitMask <> 0 then 'Set' else 'Clear' end as State
    from Bits;

-- Play with some sample data in a table.
declare @Samples as Table ( SampleId Int Identity, Number Int );
insert into @Samples ( Number ) values ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 30 ), ( 65 ), ( 16385 );
select * from @Samples;

-- Clear bit 6 in each row.
update @Samples
  set Number &= 2147483647 - Power( 2, 6 );
select * from @Samples;

-- Set bit 6 in each row.
update @Samples
  set Number |= Power( 2, 6 );
select * from @Samples;

-- Clear bit 6 in each row again.
update @Samples
  set Number &= 2147483647 - Power( 2, 6 );
select * from @Samples;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll take away the very useful bit builder cte which is something I'll find invaluable when making sense of the bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it by using [T-SQL bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188725%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as follows:

```
set nocount on;

declare @test table (id int identity primary key, bits int);

insert into @test values(63);
insert into @test values(1);

select id, cast(bits as binary(4)) as 'bits' 
from @test;

update @test
set bits = (bits & 8388575) | 128
where (bits & 32) <> 0;

select id, cast(bits as binary(4)) as 'bits' 
from @test;

/*
Outputs

id          bits
----------- ----------
1           0x0000003F
2           0x00000001

id          bits
----------- ----------
1           0x0000009F
2           0x00000001

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you masked with 6 (binary 0110), you've set bits 2 and 3 - as if you masked with 4 and then 2.

So all you can do is check for rows with those bits set. Those will be the rows that were affected - however, some of them may have already had those bits set. You will have to go through manually, or narrow the dataset somehow. Perhaps it's not valid to have certain combinations of bits set?

This query will get you the list of rows which have been masked with 6:

```
select * from table where bitfield & 6 = 6
```